# Butterknife won't generate injections in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, butterknife

When I click on setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and go to the generate menu, the "generate injections using butterknife" option is not there. I also tried using the shift-command-B shortcut but it still doesn't work. I put these two lines in my build.gradle (Module:app) file

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'

annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
```

I tried restarting Android Studio as well but nothing seems to work. Thanks to anyone who sees this!

Comment: After onCreate(), have you called ButterKnife.bind(this)?

Comment: Yeah. It looks like this:@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing a plugin. See this link https://github.com/avast/android-butterknife-zelezny/issues/98

Comment: A  link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
```

with

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:**

In Android Studio:

```
 1. File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories

 2. Search and install 'Android ButterKnife Zelezny'

 3. Restart Android Studio
```

**OPTION 2:**

If you can't find it in Browse repositories, then download plugin (link below) and install it manually via "install from disk"

Link for plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7369-android-butterknife-zelezny

Link for project: https://github.com/avast/android-butterknife-zelezny

Answer (score 0):

So if you want add butter knife add all dependency related to this and

*** Important**
                   Go to setting and then go plugin, search butter knife and install